# Is there a Android app for Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, apps

Is there an official Android app for Stack Exchange? If not, which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [official news about StackExchange android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app). Yes the alpha testing of the app is going on and as Geoff Dalgas has mentioned in post, it may take more [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) to fix bugs/issues if any.

Answer (score 2):

The mobile site of Android Enthusiasts is pretty good. But if you really want a dedicated app, have a look at https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android

Answer (score 2):

Yes!
There is now:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/